# What are the pros and cons between get_dummies (Pandas) and OneHotEncoder (Scikit-learn)?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dummy-variable

I'm learning different methods to convert categorical variables to numeric for machine-learning classifiers.  I came across the `pd.get_dummies` method and `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()` and I wanted to see how they differed in terms of performance and usage.

I found a tutorial on how to use `OneHotEncoder()` on https://xgdgsc.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/note-on-using-onehotencoder-in-scikit-learn-to-work-on-categorical-features/ since the `sklearn` documentation wasn't too helpful on this feature. I have a feeling I'm not doing it correctly...but

**Can some explain the pros and cons of using `pd.dummies` over `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()` and vice versa?** I know that `OneHotEncoder()` gives you a sparse matrix but other than that I'm not sure how it is used and what the benefits are over the `pandas` method.  Am I using it inefficiently?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
sns.set()

%matplotlib inline

#Iris Plot
iris = load_iris()
n_samples, m_features = iris.data.shape

#Load Data
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
D_target_dummy = dict(zip(np.arange(iris.target_names.shape[0]), iris.target_names))

DF_data = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=iris.feature_names)
DF_data["target"] = pd.Series(y).map(D_target_dummy)
#sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  \
#0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2   
#1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2   
#2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2   
#3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2   
#4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2   
#5                  5.4               3.9                1.7               0.4   

DF_dummies = pd.get_dummies(DF_data["target"])
#setosa  versicolor  virginica
#0         1           0          0
#1         1           0          0
#2         1           0          0
#3         1           0          0
#4         1           0          0
#5         1           0          0

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
def f1(DF_data):
    Enc_ohe, Enc_label = OneHotEncoder(), LabelEncoder()
    DF_data["Dummies"] = Enc_label.fit_transform(DF_data["target"])
    DF_dummies2 = pd.DataFrame(Enc_ohe.fit_transform(DF_data[["Dummies"]]).todense(), columns = Enc_label.classes_)
    return(DF_dummies2)

%timeit pd.get_dummies(DF_data["target"])
#1000 loops, best of 3: 777 µs per loop

%timeit f1(DF_data)
#100 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`OneHotEncoder` cannot process string values directly. If your nominal features are strings, then you need to first map them into integers.

`pandas.get_dummies` is kind of the opposite. By default, it only converts string columns into one-hot representation, unless columns are specified.

Comment: Other than that, is one efficient over other?

Comment: update, `OneHotEncoder` can not be applied on strings as well in 0.20.0 version.

Comment: @BsHe No longer true in sklearn 0.20.3: `OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['good','bad','worst','good', 'good', 'bad'])))` works, which means `OneHotEncoder` can be applied on stirngs.

Comment: @dzieciou Good for updating.

Comment: You cannot encode new unseen data with `pd.get_dummies`.

Answer (score 249):

**For machine learning, you almost definitely want to use `sklearn.OneHotEncoder`.** For other tasks like simple analyses, you might be able to use `pd.get_dummies`, which is a bit more convenient.

Note that `sklearn.OneHotEncoder` has been updated in the latest version so that it **does accept strings** for categorical variables, as well as integers.

The crux of it is that the `sklearn` encoder creates a function which **persists** and can **then be applied to new data sets which use the same categorical variables, with consistent results**.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Create the encoder.
encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
encoder.fit(X_train)    # Assume for simplicity all features are categorical.

# Apply the encoder.
X_train = encoder.transform(X_train)
X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)
```

Note how we apply the same encoder we created via `X_train` to the new data set `X_test`.

Consider what happens if `X_test` contains different levels than `X_train` for one of its variables. For example, let's say `X_train["color"]` contains only `"red"` and `"green"`, but in addition to those, `X_test["color"]` sometimes contains `"blue"`.

If we use `pd.get_dummies`, `X_test` will end up with an additional `"color_blue"` column which `X_train` doesn't have, and the inconsistency will probably break our code later on, especially if we are feeding `X_test` to an `sklearn` model which we trained on `X_train`.

And if we want to process the data like this in production, where we're receiving a single example at a time, `pd.get_dummies` won't be of use.

With `sklearn.OneHotEncoder` on the other hand, once we've created the encoder, we can reuse it to produce the same output every time, with columns only for `"red"` and `"green"`. And we can explicitly control what happens when it encounters the new level `"blue"`: if we think that's impossible, then we can tell it to throw an error with `handle_unknown="error"`; otherwise we can tell it to continue and simply set the red and green columns to 0, with `handle_unknown="ignore"`.

Comment: I believe this answer has far greater impact than the accepted. The real magic is handling unknown categorical features which are bound to pop up in production.

Comment: I think this is a better, more complete answer than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes. IMHO, this is a better answer than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yup . This answer definitely explains better why one_hot_encoder might be better along with a clear example

Comment: Additional note; there are many other encoders in sklearn. When to use which, depends upon the data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63822728/5114585 might help you understand some common encoder's uses

Comment: What about if the categorical variables one needs to transform contain missing values?

Comment: @ErnestoLopezFune I think we can handle the missing value of categorical before the OneHotEncoder by imputation or with pipelines easiest way. 

# Preprocessing for categorical data
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

It will replace with the "most_frequent" value.

Answer (score 9):

I really like Carl's answer and upvoted it.  I will just expand Carl's example a bit so that more people hopefully will appreciate that pd.get_dummies can handle unknown.  The two examples below shows that pd.get_dummies can accomplish the same thing in handling unknown as OHE .

```
# data is from @dzieciou's comment above
>>> data =pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['good','bad','worst','good', 'good', 'bad']))
# new_data has two values that data does not have. 
>>> new_data= pd.DataFrame(
pd.Series(['good','bad','worst','good', 'good', 'bad','excellent', 'perfect']))
```

### Using pd.get_dummies

```
>>> df = pd.get_dummies(data)
>>> col_list = df.columns.tolist()
>>> print(df)
   0_bad  0_good  0_worst
0      0       1        0
1      1       0        0
2      0       0        1
3      0       1        0
4      0       1        0
5      1       0        0
6      0       0        0
7      0       0        0

>>> new_df = pd.get_dummies(new_data)
# handle unknow by using .reindex and .fillna()
>>> new_df = new_df.reindex(columns=col_list).fillna(0.00)
>>> print(new_df)
#    0_bad  0_good  0_worst
# 0      0       1        0
# 1      1       0        0
# 2      0       0        1
# 3      0       1        0
# 4      0       1        0
# 5      1       0        0
# 6      0       0        0
# 7      0       0        0
```

### Using OneHotEncoder

```
>>> encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse=False)
>>> encoder.fit(data)
>>> encoder.transform(new_data)
# array([[0., 1., 0.],
#        [1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 1.],
#        [0., 1., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 0.],
#        [1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Can you please expand your answer to include an example with drop_first =True, and then also show new data that doesn't include the dropped value.

Answer (score 6):

why wouldn't you just cache or save the columns as variable col_list from the resulting get_dummies then use pd.reindex to align the train vs test datasets....   example:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(data)
col_list = df.columns.tolist()

new_df = pd.get_dummies(new_data)
new_df = new_df.reindex(columns=col_list).fillna(0.00)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: more to refute the previous comment that Sklearn OHE is supperior because of handle_unknown. The same can be accomplished using pandas reindex.

Comment: There can be a sneaky problem with using get_dummies except as a one off run. What happens if you have drop_first=True and the next sample doesn't include the dropped value?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked long ago, but is still relevant in 2023.

In one sentence: Both can be used for the task, which one to choose depends on personal preference and other circumstances.

In a bit more detail:

- For both OneHotEncoder and get_dummies it is possible and the most robust way to explicitly specify the categories. For OneHotEncoder this can be achieved using the "categories" parameter, which is a list-of-lists. For get_dummies you need to convert the relevant columns to categorical with the appropriate categories.
- OneHotEncoder assumes you want to encode all columns in your data, so if it is not the case you have to either manually select/transform/join-with-original-columns or wrap the OneHotEncoder in a column transformer. This is much easier using get_dummies.
- If you like to stay in DataFrame space during your data processing pipeline, then pandas.get_dummies is the most direct way, but if you rely on scikit Pipeline-s then OneHotEncoder wrapped in a column transformer is more straightforward.

For a full explanation with examples read [my article on towards data science.](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-hot-encoding-scikit-vs-pandas-2133775567b8)