# What is difference between pd.get_dummies and sklearn one hot encoder in python?

Tags: python, pandas, keras, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

What is difference between pd.get_dummies and sklearn one hot encoder in python ? As per my knowledge both do same works,Can any one tells what is the main difference between pd.get_dummies and sklearn one hot encoder ,on which  one  is more efficient at present.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply,but which one is more efficient as compare to both ways,the differennce is only i identify in that post, pandas get_duimmies can directly converts strings columns data into integer columns , where in case of one hot encoder we have explicilty define our mapping , After that it will convert other than this is there difference .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Output difference**

`pd.get_dummies` results to a Pandas DataFrame whereas `OneHotEncoder` results a SciPy CSR matrix.

Example -

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64

type(pd.get_dummies(s))
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit_transform(s.values.reshape(-1, 1))#.toarray() # Can be converted to NumPy ndarray using .toarray
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

---

**2. Time complexity**

`pd.get_dummies` is much faster than the `OneHotEncoder`

```
Example -
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*50000)
len(s)
250000

%timeit pd.get_dummies(s)
15.2 ms ± 227 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit enc.fit_transform(s.values.reshape(-1, 1))
34.1 ms ± 5.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit enc.fit_transform(s.values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray() # more reusable
45.3 ms ± 5.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**3. Input data dependency**

As explained in the old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38650886/10734525)

Comment: Thanks for clear explination on my query.Present it was clean and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I feel one of the key differentiation is `.transform` in one hot encoder.

If you are planning use this dummy variables generation on the test data and 
let us assume we have following situation:

```
enc.transform(pd.Series([1,3,2]).values.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

#it will create consistent columns as that of the training data (all 5 features)
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

But pd.get_dummies work independently on the test data

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.Series([1,3,2]))

#
    1   2   3
0   1   0   0
1   0   0   1
2   0   1   0
```