# Differencies between OneHotEncoding (sklearn) and get_dummies (pandas)

Tags: python, training-data, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I am wondering what is the difference between pandas' `get_dummies()` encoding of categorical features as compared to the sklearn's `OneHotEncoder()`.

I've seen answers that mention that `get_dummies()` cannot produce encoding for categories not seen in the training dataset ([answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631163/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-between-get-dummies-pandas-and-onehotencoder-sciki)). However, this is a result of having performed the `get_dummies()` separately on the testing and training datasets (which can give inconsistent shapes). On the other hand, if we applied the `get_dummies()` on the original dataset, before splitting it, I think the two methods should give identical results. Am I wrong? Would that cause problems?

My code is currently working like the one below:

```
def one_hot_encode(ds,feature):
    #get DF of dummy variables
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(ds[feature])
    #One dummy variable to drop (Dummy Trap)
    dummyDrop = dummies.columns[0]
    #Create a DF from the original and the dummies' DF
    #Drop the original categorical variable and the one dummy
    final =  pd.concat([ds,dummies], axis='columns').drop([feature,dummyDrop], axis='columns')
    return final

#Get data DF
dataset = pd.read_csv("census_income_dataset.csv")
columns = dataset.columns

#Perform one-hot-encoding on the DF (See function above) on categorical features
features = ["workclass","marital_status","occupation","relationship","race","sex","native_country"]
for f in features:
    dataset = one_hot_encode(dataset,f)
#Re-order to get ouput feature in last column
dataset = dataset[[c for c in dataset.columns if c!="income_level"]+["income_level"]]
dataset.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you apply `get_dummies()` and `OneHotEncoder()` in the general dataset, you should obtain the same result.

If you apply `get_dummies()` in the general dataset, and `OneHotEncoder()` in the train dataset, you will probably obtain a few (very small) differences if in the test data you have a "new" category. If not, they should have the same result.

**The main difference** between `get_dummies()` and `OneHotEncoder()` is how they work when you are using this **model in real life** (or in production) and your receive **a "new" class of a categorical column that you haven't faced before**

***Example:*** Imagine your category "sex" can be only: *male* or *female*, and you sold your model to a company. What will happen if now, the category "sex" receives the value: "NA" (not applicable)? *(Also, you can image that "NA" is an option, but it only appear 0.001%, and casually, you don't have any of this value in your dataset)*

Using `get_dummies()`, you will have a problem, since your model is trained for only 2 different categories of sex, and now,  you have a different and new category that the model can't hand with it.

Using `OneHotEncoder()`, will allow you to "ignore" this new category that your model can't face, allowing you to keep the same shape between the model input, and your new sample input.

That's why people uses `OneHotEncoder()` in train set and not in the general dataset, they are "simulating" this type of success (having "new" class you haven't faced before in a categorical column)

Comment: It is pretty easy to maintain only features in your train set using `get_dummies` with a simple join to a dataframe, or using `not in` if working with `numpy`, etc...