# onehot encoding and pandas using scikit learn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

im building one hot encoding function from and pandas dataframe and cant figure out how to get the data back into the dataframe.  I get :

> "**IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid
> indices**

How do I reintegrate this back into pandas data frame?

```
def one_hot_encoder (features, df_to_encode):
    """encoder to encoder  

    Parameters:
    features (list): features to normalise
    df_to_encode (pandas dataframe): dataframe to encode

    Returns:
    dataframe: dataframe to encode 
    """
   from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder    
   for column in features: 
        # one hot encoder 
        enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
        column_norm = column + "_encoded"
        df = enc.fit_transform(df_to_encode[[column]])

    return df

columns_to_one_hot_encode = ["type"]
df = one_hot_encoder(columns_to_one_hot_encode,df)
```

The data im using is from https://www.kaggle.com/ealaxi/paysim1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get_feature_names` that is built-in SciKit's `OneHotEncoder` and then subsequently drop the old column. In this way, you can still use `OneHotEncoder` instead of `pd.get_dummies`

```
import pandas as pd

def one_hot_encoder (features, df_to_encode):
    """encoder to encoder  

    Parameters:
    features (list): features to normalise
    df_to_encode (pandas dataframe): dataframe to encode

    Returns:
    dataframe: dataframe to encode 
    """  
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    for column in features: 
       enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
       df_enc = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(df_to_encode[[column]]))
       df_enc.columns = enc.get_feature_names([column])
       df_to_encode.drop(column, axis = 1, inplace = True)
       df_fin = pd.concat([df_to_encode, df_enc], axis = 1)

       
       return df_fin


columns_to_one_hot_encode = ["type"]
df = one_hot_encoder(columns_to_one_hot_encode,df)
```

Comment: I've used get_Feature _names but looks like its going to be DEPRECATED.  It says  get_feature_names is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't get that warning, but after reading SciKit's documentation, I think you can change this to: get_feature_names_out().

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sklearn`, you can simply use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```
import pandas as pd

def one_hot_encoder (features, df_to_encode):
    """encoder to encoder  

    Parameters:
    features (list): features to normalise
    df_to_encode (pandas dataframe): dataframe to encode

    Returns:
    dataframe: dataframe to encode 
    """
    return pd.get_dummies(df_to_encode, columns=features)

columns_to_one_hot_encode = ["type"]
df = one_hot_encoder(columns_to_one_hot_encode, df)
```

Comment: Whats the difference between get_dummies and scikits OneHotEncoder ?

Comment: @resolver101 What do you mean?  They are two different implementations on two different libraries of the same concept. But if you are using `pandas` anyway, it's easier if use `pandas.get_dummies`. As you can see, this solution is much simpler than the other. I don't know what made you change your mind and accept the other.

Comment: @HarrPlotter You are right that for a simple transformation you can easily use the get.dummies(). However, as stated in this* post as well, OneHotEncoder() has some advantages over get_dummies. The main one, in my opinion, is the fact that you can easily apply the OneHotEncoder object to your test data which uses the same categories and results. Given that the dataset is for a Kaggle competition, I think OneHotEncoder() is the wiser choice.

* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631163/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-between-get-dummies-pandas-and-onehotencoder-sciki